# Dojo - EnhancedGrid is not getting displayed on 1st time page load

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid, dojo.gridx

I have a following EnhancedGrid:

```
var newGrid = new EnhancedGrid({
                         store : this.resultStore,
                         structure : this.resultGridLayout,
                         autoHeight:true
                     });

newGrid.placeAt(this.resultGridNode);
newGrid.startup();
```

I have placed grid under a "dijit.layout.TabContainer" and this tab is not selected by default.

When the Page is loaded for the 1st time Table doesnt appear...
or rather i would say a Table appers like a line.. when i checked using firebug, found that data is present however height and width of dojoxGridMasterHeader and other grid related css classes are zero...
 Next time when i make changes in some input parameter which changes values in grid, the table appears..

Tried the solutions provided in following thread, which didnt work for me: [EnhancedGrid in a TabContainer not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746946/enhancedgrid-in-a-tabcontainer-not-working#)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to startup the widget?

```
newGrid.startup();
```

And then place it to the DOM.

```
newGrid.placeAt(this.resultGridNode);
```

Comment: hi.. thanks for replying.. yes i have tried this.. its not working.. Table appers like a line.. when i checked using firebug, found that data is present however height and width are zero...

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced a similar issue working with dijit.layout.TabContainer and Gridx. You should call resize() method  of the tab on its first appearance. You may also choose to call  resize() on tabSwitch listener.

Code should look something like :

```
tabContainer.selectedChildWidget.resize()
```

But it really depends on how you are using the container.